# C: Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

Im writing this program for a class assignment in C. Its to simulate reading and writing to a custom-sized direct-mapped cache, involving a custom-sized main memory.

These are the parameters I used before getting `Segmentation fault`:

```
Enter main memory size (words):  65536
Enter cache size (words):  1024
Enter block size (words/block):  16
```

This is my code. Its not complete yet.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct cache{
     int tag;
     int *block;
};

struct main {
     int value;
     int address;
     int word;

     struct main *next;
};

struct cache   *cacheptr;
struct main    *mainHd;

int main() {
    int option = 0;

    while (option != 4) {
        printf("Main memory to Cache memory mapping:\n--------------------------------------");
        printf("\n1) Set parameters\n2) Read cache\n3) Write to cache\n4) Exit\n\nEnter Selection: ");
        scanf("%d",&option);
        printf("\n");

        if (option == 1) {
            int mainMemory, cacheSize, block;

            printf("Enter main memory size (words):  ");
            scanf("%d",&mainMemory);

            printf("Enter cache size (words):  ");
            scanf("%d",&cacheSize);

            printf("Enter block size (words/block):  ");
            scanf("%d",&block);

            struct main *mainptr=(struct main *)malloc(cacheSize);
            mainHd->next=mainptr;

            for (int i=1; i < mainMemory; i++) {
                mainptr->value=mainMemory-i;
                mainptr->address=i;
                mainptr->word=i;

                struct main *mainnxt=(struct main *)malloc(cacheSize);
                mainptr->next=mainnxt;
                mainptr=mainnxt;
            }
        } /* end if */
    } /* end while */
} /* end main */
```

Comment: could you please format the code nicely as a first step (e.g. eliminate all the blank lines, indent it properly, ...) so it's not a huge hassle to read it? thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Three issues:

1. These

   ```
   struct main *mainptr=(struct main *)malloc(cacheSize);
   struct main *mainnxt=(struct main *)malloc(cacheSize);
   ```

   needs to be

   ```
   struct main *mainptr = malloc(cacheSize * sizeof *mainptr);
   struct main *mainnxt = malloc(cacheSize * sizeof *mainnxt);
   ```

   because

   1. [Casting the result of `malloc` (and family) is not required in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)
   2. You should supply the number of *bytes* for allocating to `malloc` and not just the amount of `struct main` you want to allocate.
2. You need to allocate memory for `mainHd` before using it here:

   ```
   mainHd->next=mainptr;
   ```

   Something like

   ```
   mainHd = malloc(sizeof *mainHd);
   ```

   will do the trick!
3. Don't forget to `free` the allocated memory after its use.

*Side note:* Check the result of `malloc` to see if it was successful.